# computer randomly forgets settings and folders, sometimes logs out

Tags: linux, security, hardware-failure, persistence

for some longer time i'm having problem with computer (or even computers as it was happening on two computers) not saving settings. i shutdown every electronics at night so every day is a reboot. and for example - if on monday i set a cat pic for wallpaper, it will disappear somewhere at weekend. or maybe even thursday. totally randomly.
i checked whole network (via wireshark) if some hacker inside doesn't mess with computer but best i saw with closed browser was my computer replying to itself and to my ISP (nothing special). i know i opened ports for this computer and i host sometimes some websites (in a model of work-hours ofcourse as i turn off at night) and i know someone could use it but as we see wireshark empty. checked ports too and also nothing suspicious.
thought also if it could be a hardware problem as my computer is quite old (about 8 year).
specification is:

- CPU - intel i3 2.53 GhZ
- GPU - some builtin amd radeon (saw this info in x11 settings, don't know exact version/model/something)
- storage - originally 256GB HDD but it got broken and moved to 16GB USB storage (pendrive). ofcourse with enabled persistence

> note - current storage have filesystem problem as gparted sees (or more doesn't see) main partition but shows instead disk config from before system installation (did this OS installed swap, home and root partition with ext4 inside big iso9660 partition? )

- RAM - initally builtin 3GB but i added lots of swap (on one pendrive it is half GB and on second few GBs)
- OS - `#!++` (modded debian with x11/openbox)

just that i don't think it's a hardware failure due to randomness of this bug/crash/something.
any idea what causes computer to forget settings?

Comment: How do you set the wallpaper? Where is that setting stored? Is it the setting that disappears, or the whole image file?

Comment: Its in openbox config. Idk where exactly...

Comment: How do you *change* the setting, then?

Comment: In menu there is app "wallpaper settings"